# Filtering Interpolation method for Core Image sampler

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-image

I am using Core Image to implement my custom image processing filter. The kernel has two input sampler parameters:

```
kernel vec4 filterk(sampler image, sampler db)
```

The last sampler is a look up table and data mutation is not desired to happen.
When I am retrieving values from db sampler seems some interpolation is applied.

I have implemented this filter on Android using OpenGL shader and set filtering modes GL_NEAREST:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

With these parameters set all works correct(in contrary when GL_LINEAR is set).

Here the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_advanced_concepts/ci.advanced_concepts.html) says that default interpolation for CISampler is the  bilinear interpolation and there exists also nearest neighbor.

How I can create CISampler and set interpolation method to nearest neighbor on iOS SDK?

P.S.
Also, Core Image Kernel Language [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CIKernelLangRef/ci_gslang_ext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004397-CH206-BAJBIGJJ) says that there is a __table keyword which makes sampler to used as a lookup table. But XCode reports about error when this keyword is used: unknown type name '__table'.

P.P.S.

Tried to create CIImage using initWithTexture and used texture for which filtering properties had been set to GL_NEAREST. This did not work too and again [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/) says that CIImage ignores filtering and wrap modes since CISampler overrides them.

Answer (score 0):

You would needs to utilize the CISampler class that is not available on iOS: [Open Radar](http://www.openradar.appspot.com/15376683). That means specifying the interpolation is not possible at this time.

On Mac OS X (or when the class becomes available on iOS) you would specify kCISamplerFilterNearest for the kCISamplerFilterMode option key for your CISampler. See [CISampler Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CISampler_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Sampler_Option_Keys)

Example:

```
CISampler* src = [CISampler samplerWithImage:inputImage options:
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kCISamplerFilterNearest, kCISamplerFilterMode, nil]];
```

Comment: It seems that CISampler is not available for iOS SDK.
Did you try  this on your side?

Comment: My apologies, I should have looked at the docs better. Please see updated answer.

Comment: `CISampler` is available in iOS 9.0 and later now. The answer needs so editing on that ;) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CISampler_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Sampler_Option_Keys